# Count strpos() Occurences

Tags: php, arrays, string, count

How can I count found occurrences of a keyword? Currently I have this

```
$filesfound = false;
foreach ($arr as $file)
$filesfound = true;
...
```

```
echo $vouchers = ($filesfound === true) && (strpos(implode('/', $file), 'Voucher') !== false) ? '<div>+ 2 Files Available</div>' : '';
```

I am trying to get "+2 files available" to actually account for the string occurences found. How can I do this? Multiple functions give no result I am expecting. In this case, **I am expecting a correct read of 2**

Thanks!!

---

**SOLUTION**

```
$filesfound = false;
foreach ($arr as $file) {
   // If occurrences were found. Returns 0 for each match, so we add + 1
   if (strpos(implode('/', $file), 'Voucher') === 0) { 
      $filesfound = true;
      $count = $count + 1; 
   } 
}
echo $count;
```

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php is the only function I know of that keeps a count. `strpos` is the position in the string, not the number of strings.

Comment: Are you looking for keywords in the name of the file? Or inside the contents of the files? What's in `$arr`?

Comment: I will try that, however is there a solution that lighter on CPU? I have high traffic,  I try to avoid regular expressions unless its JS, where the client's browser takes the expenses.

Comment: $arr is a array of keys found within file data using a class parser, which is read from the database blob field. From there it implodes and displays the list of files. From there, we just need to count the occurrences of txt files containing the name "voucher" outside of the iteration.

Comment: Maybe substr_count()? https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr-count

Comment: Apparently, in the iteration I can do this - $var = strpos(implode('/', $file), 'Voucher'); if ($var === 0) { $count = $count + 1; }  <after loop> echo $count -  This provided the desired result - a count of 2 ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### To count occurrences of a text within a string, you can use:

```php
$text = 'This is a test';
// find how many "is" are within our $text variable:
echo substr_count($text, 'is'); // this will return 2, since there are 2 of "is" in our $text
```